# Why doesn't this alert show up on my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following code is in my ViewController implementation, the first block is Google Maps integration and the second one is the alert. The compiler didn't throw any errors. Why is it that my alert does not show up?

```
    -(void) loadView {

    GMSCameraPosition * camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: 51.50
            longitude: -0.11
            zoom: 15
    ];
    GMSMapView * mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame: CGRectZero camera: camera];
    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeTerrain;
    UIEdgeInsets mapInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 300.0);
    mapView.padding = mapInsets;
    NSLog(@ "User's location: %@", mapView.myLocation);
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker * marker = [
            [GMSMarker alloc] init
    ];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.50, -0.11);
    marker.title = @ "London innit";
    marker.snippet = @ "UK";
    marker.map = mapView;
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @ "My Alert"
            message: @ "This is an alert."
            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert
    ];

    UIAlertAction * defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @ "OK"
            style: UIAlertActionStyleDefault
            handler: ^ (UIAlertAction * action) {}
    ];

    [alert addAction: defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController: alert animated: YES completion: nil];
 }

  @end
```

Comment: check one your console what the waring you get

Comment: I think, you may presenting alert view controller on null, means you are presenting alert view controller on a view controller that is deallocating.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in `loadView`, show your alert in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: I put it in viewDidLoad, but still nothing. Here's the message from the console: 2017-03-02 10:20:22.696 FlightPlanningApp[10934:140826] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f99ad713e80> on <ViewController: 0x7f99ad407660> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2017-03-02 10:20:22.711 FlightPlanningApp[10934:140826] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f99ad525360> on <ViewController: 0x7f99ad407660> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: You can not and should not present/push any view before its viewWillAppear is called. Try showing alert in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear methods

Comment: I have now put the appropriate code in the -(void)viewDidAppear method but still nothing. It drops the same error. I suspect it has something to do with "not being in the window hierarchy" as the error message suggests above. Any tips?

Comment: If you are not using autolayout, remmeber to set the autosizing mask: self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;, otherwise the width and height won't be modified by the parents.